# When using Hbase shell the save-history option for ruby (.irbrc) is not working

Tags: hbase

Save history is presently working on normal irb (jruby) shell.  But for some reason it is not working when using hbase shell.

I have seen history working on hbase shell on other boxes in the past following the same procedures as now described and they did work, so not sure what small detail i may have missed this time around.

I have put inside ~/.irbrc the following:

```
$ cat  ~/.irbrc
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"
```

Did it take when launching irb? yes..

```
hbase(main):001:0>   puts IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE]
/home/stephenb/.irb-save-history

:AT_EXIT=>[#<Proc:0x6bb5eba4@/shared/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/ext/save-history.rb:67
```

Does this jruby script exist? yes ..

```
$ ll /shared/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/ext/save-history.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephenb stephenb 2119 Feb 21 07:53 /shared/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/ext/save-history.rb
```

Does  hbase shell  history work?  Well, NOT FOR HBASE commands. But it DOES show stuff from prior IRB sessions (non HBASE)

```
$ date
Mon Jun  3 12:28:41 PDT 2013
stephenb@gondolin:/shared/git2/etl/appminer/hive$ hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.92.2, r1379292, Fri Aug 31 13:13:53 UTC 2012

hbase(main):001:0> describe 'app'
DESCRIPTION                                                                              ENABLED                                         
 {NAME => 'app', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'm', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE =>  true                                            
 '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647',                                                  
 BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}                                                                     
1 row(s) in 0.4500 seconds

hbase(main):002:0> quit
$ ll /home/stephenb/.irb-save-history
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephenb stephenb 73 Jun  3 12:05 /home/stephenb/.irb-save-history
```

As you can see from the 'date' before invoking 'hbase shell' and the modified date of the history file afterwards the history file is not updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem. After a bit of googling I found this post: http://www.nosql.se/page/2/ which gives a solution. The .irbrc file  must be as follows:

```
# cat .irbrc
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"
Kernel.at_exit do
    IRB.conf[:AT_EXIT].each do |i|
        i.call
    end
end
```

I can't say why (I don't want to learn Ruby) but it works. Hope it helps.

Comment: It would be useful if someone were able to explain why this solution works in order to give a more complete answer.

Comment: @w5m  I agree. But noone "stepped up" so I awarded anyways since the answer did help.

Comment: I found out the reason it works.  The Kernel.at_exit is required to actually save the entries. The HBase book does NOT include this information and thus does NOT work.  Ref: http://hbase.apache.org/book/shell_tricks.html